# PyGObject - left-click menu on a status icon

Tags: python, gtk, gnome, pygobject

I'm starting to write a small panel applet for Gnome and I'd like the user to be able to left-click on the status icon to see some options and information e.g. similar to sound icon in Gnome 3, where you can set volume via left-click while set preferences via right-click.
Right-click code is this:

```
statusicon.connect("popup-menu", right_button_click)
```

where `right_button_click` is the name of the function that gets called on right-click event. The important part is [`"popup-menu"`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkstatusicon.html#signal-gtkstatusicon--popup-menu). What would be alternative for setting left-click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to look into the gnome code for the volume control, and that's is [this](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center)
Second, you should look into the API documentation for GtkStatusIcon, and that one is [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusIcon.html)
That should be enough.

Comment: I need to do this in python with PyGObject (successor of PyGtk).

Comment: @Rainbow It is almost the same thing, since PyGObject are bindings for Gtk+ c library.

Answer (score 5):

This is the tiny example showing how it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk

class TrayIcon(Gtk.StatusIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.StatusIcon.__init__(self)
        self.set_from_icon_name('help-about')
        self.set_has_tooltip(True)
        self.set_visible(True)
        self.connect("popup_menu", self.on_secondary_click)


    def on_secondary_click(self, widget, button, time):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()

        menu_item1 = Gtk.MenuItem("First Entry")
        menu.append(menu_item1)

        menu_item2 = Gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
        menu.append(menu_item2)
        menu_item2.connect("activate", Gtk.main_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        menu.popup(None, None, None, self, 3, time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tray = TrayIcon()

    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but i'm just posting this in case someone else ever looks for left click control over gtkstatusicon.

The direct alternative is

```
statusicon.connect("activate", left_button_click)
```

This is a sample for trayicon popup menu working with left click instead of the (common) right click.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class TrayIcon(gtk.StatusIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.StatusIcon.__init__(self)
        self.set_from_icon_name('help-about')
        self.set_has_tooltip(True)
        self.set_visible(True)
        self.connect("activate", self.on_click)

    def greetme(self,data=None):  
        msg=gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL,gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, gtk.BUTTONS_OK, "Greetings")
        msg.run()
        msg.destroy()

    def on_click(self,data): 
        event=gtk.get_current_event()
        btn=event.button #this gets the button value of gtk event.
        time=gtk.get_current_event_time() # required by menu popup. 

        menu = gtk.Menu()
        menu_item1 = gtk.MenuItem("First Entry")
        menu.append(menu_item1)
        menu_item1.connect("activate", self.greetme)

        menu_item2 = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
        menu.append(menu_item2)
        menu_item2.connect("activate", gtk.main_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        menu.popup(None, None, None, btn, time) 
        #button can be hardcoded (i.e 1) but time must be correct.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tray = TrayIcon()
    gtk.main()
```

Also , there is this alternative :

```
statusicon.connect("button-press-event", button_click)
```

Bellow sample code raise the same popup menu in gtktrayicon in BOTH right and left click.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class TrayIcon(gtk.StatusIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.StatusIcon.__init__(self)
        self.set_from_icon_name('help-about')
        self.set_has_tooltip(True)
        self.set_visible(True)
        self.connect("button-press-event", self.on_click)

    def greetme(self,data=None):  
        msg=gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL,gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, gtk.BUTTONS_OK, "Greetings")
        msg.run()
        msg.destroy()

    def on_click(self,data,event):
    #event in this case is sent by the status icon connect. 
        btn=event.button 
        #By controlling this event.button value (1-2-3 for left-middle-right click) you can call other functions.
        time=gtk.get_current_event_time() # required by the popup. 

        menu = gtk.Menu()
        menu_item1 = gtk.MenuItem("First Entry")
        menu.append(menu_item1)
        menu_item1.connect("activate", self.greetme) 

        menu_item2 = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
        menu.append(menu_item2)
        menu_item2.connect("activate", gtk.main_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        menu.popup(None, None, None, btn, time) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tray = TrayIcon()
    gtk.main()
```

Hope above code helps.
George V.